# What are the consequences laptop running out power while GParted is running?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I was fixing my partition with GParted and it seemed to work well.

But, my laptop suddenly ran out of power and I didn't realize it, then it turned off while GParted was still running which was at the part it is copying 2MB per second(on
    `/dev/sda8`)

Then, I plugged in battery cable and checked. All system seems normal.

My question is:

- Since there is no important data in `/dev/sda8` , will any problems arise because of what happened? I already checked all the data in `/dev/sda8`, and there is no corrupted data.

**Output of sudo fdisk -l:**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00075eb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   212719615   106256384    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       212721664  1953519615   870398976    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       212725760   410556415    98915328   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1937895424  1953519615     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       410560512   508213247    48826368   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       508215296  1937888819   714836762    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

gives no error/warning messages

Screenshot of my partition table with GParted + details on un-allocated data:

[image]

ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit 
running gParted with live usb

Answer (score 0):

*Theoretical and short answer:*
yes, something could have gone wrong (though not very likely in your specific case).

*Just to be sure that all is well:*
The best thing you can do is running a filesystemcheck on any of the filesystems you have.
(let windows check NTFS, let linux check the ext partitions , etc).
If everything checks out OK and you are not missing any personal/data files, there shouldn't be any reason to worry.

The commandline tool to check the integrity of your linux filesystems is: **fsck**
The graphical tool for filesystemcheck under ubuntu is: **palimpsest**

Comment: For the Windows side of things (if there is an NTFS partition present), the relevant command from a command prompt would be `chkdsk volume /f`, e.g. `chkdsk C: /f` if the drive to be checked is mounted as C:. The `/f` switch attempts to automatically fix any problems with the filesystem.