# 1 suspicious file with size 140TB?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, hard-drive

**SOLVED**

**please see the bottom answer for my solution**

After I use GParted to fix my partition(GParted ran well but my laptop shutt down because it ran out battery power and didn't finish the process copying my other partition, [details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263152/laptop-runs-out-power-while-gparted-still-runningcopying-2mb-per-sec-what-are)),

I notice that I got 10GB increase in my Ubuntu partition, then I checked and found 1 suspicious file with size 140TB in /proc...

Is this a problem?

[image]

ubuntu 12.04 lts 64bit

**UPDATE**

I hope these details can help

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

OUTPUT

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00075eb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   212719615   106256384    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       212721664  1953519615   870398976    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       212725760   410556415    98915328   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1937895424  1953519615     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       410560512   508213247    48826368   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       508215296  1937888819   714836762    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

**ADDED**

I think the sudden increase 10GB in my Ubuntu partition is because unfinished GParted process, I currently have 27GB in used (when I right click in filesystem then check properties) , but disk analyzer says another thing(it says I am only using 12-13GB)

[image]

Comment: Looks like something has become corrupt on that drive. Backup data and start again :)

Comment: oh God.. that's my ubuntu partition, i used gParted to fix misaligned partition before i realized that.. what should i do?

Comment: If gparted did not finish running, then anything is possible. There is no way to know that everything on that drive is fine. It's a 1TB drive, so how can you have a 140TB file. Have you run `fsck` on it?

Comment: Searching on Google for "huge kcore file" shows lots of results. Maybe check some of those too. Not all files in `/proc` are *real* files.

Comment: erm please see my post update, gparted did not finish running when i was fixing the other partition which is /dev/sda8, then i check all the data in /dev/sda8 no corrupt, and ubuntu runs normally no error all software is good..

Comment: Don't run `fsck` on a mounted partition.

Comment: oh ya my bad forgot lol sry, but i read some documentation about fsck... i dont  know but i just dont understand how to use it correctly, can u please give me what arguments after fsck? in the documentation it has alot of arguments after the word fsck and i dont know which one to use

Comment: fsck can be run from Grub (see [this question for a screenshot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)).

Comment: This is probably obvious, but I'll mention this for the future visitors just in case: you should never ever EVER run gparted while on battery power :)

Comment: Please add solutions as answers, not in original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that 140TB kcore is a problem.

As [gropiuskalle](http://forums.opensuse.org/members/gropiuskalle.html) said in one [forum](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/64-bit/436813-proc-kcore-extremely-huge-file.html): "/proc/kcore is an image of your RAM created by the Kernel to give you respective information, it's not actually a file you could delete but a virtual filesystem and it does not actually take harddisk-space."

Also, mine kcore has the same size as yours:

[image]

That doesn't mean you don't have other problem caused by an interruption of gparted.

Regards.

Comment: ah yes, after my gparted process didnt finish correecty(especially when it was copying with 2MB / s on my /dev/sda8) i start linux and realized i got about 10GB increase in use for root( /dev/sda5 ) partition.. what should i do?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Boot from a live cd and do a filesystem check; or 2) Backup your files and re-install Ubuntu (best option for me).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

finally i managed to find why +10GB sudden increase happened to my ubuntu partition, if u guys have any trouble/problem like me (gParted did not finish) please [read this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1122670) i hope it can help u.

explanation of my solution as follows :

gParted did not finish when moving my /dev/sda8 , then there's impact on my ubuntu root partition(+10 GB) i dont know why this happens but i believe its something with gParted.

when i check my trash(both user's and root's) **~/.local/share/Trash** and **/root/.local/share/Trash** respectively, there's file(s) / folder(s) with size like 14GB (please note that i cleaned up my trash before i used gParted, and im pretty sure my trash is empty and my ubuntu partition only use less than 15GB) i just simply delete it and like normally i got free space.

**note :** i simply delete it because i know when i was having trouble with /dev/sda8 , there isn't any important files in that partition.